# Vector Calculus Q

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm not confident on how to find the limits on this question, any pointers would be appreciated.

Using plane polar coordinates, evaluate:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac {x}{\sqrt{3}}}^{2 -\frac {x}{\sqrt{3}}} \frac {dydx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I see the region is a triangle, it's just not obvious to me how $r$ and $\phi$ move. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the boundary segment touching the origin and closest to the positive $x$-axis is $\phi=\frac1{\sqrt{3}},$ which corresponds to the angle $\frac\pi6.$

The other boundary segment touching the origin lies on the positive $y$-axis, which corresponds to the angle $\phi=\frac\pi2.$

The outer limit is on the line $$x+y\sqrt{3}=2\sqrt3,$$ meaning (in polar) $$r\cos\phi+r\sin\phi\sqrt3=2\sqrt3,$$ or equivalently $$r=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\cos\phi+\sin\phi\sqrt3}.$$ Your inner limit is of course $r=0$.

---

We can actually do slightly better with our outer limit. Note that $$\frac{\cos\phi+\sin\phi\sqrt3}2=\frac12\cos\phi+\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin\phi=\sin\frac\pi6\cos\phi+\cos\frac\pi6\sin\phi=\sin\left(\phi+\frac\pi6\right)$$ by angle sum formula. Hence, our outer limit is $$r=\sqrt{3}\csc\left(\phi+\frac\pi6\right).$$

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.

Comment: No problem. Check my edited answer for a slightly nicer outer limit.

Comment: Brill. $\sqrt{3}$ $ln3$ I think it is then.